# join two tables in JDO spring

Tags: spring, join, annotations, jdo

i am developing a system using JDO spring. I want to get data using mysql joining.
My tables are:

User_Login: user_id, user_name, user_password,user_role_id

User_Role: id, role

my required sql is:

```
SELECT `A0`.`USER_ID`,`B0`.`ROLE` FROM `USER_LOGIN` `A0` INNER JOIN 
`USER_ROLE` `B0` ON `A0`.`USER_ROLE_ID` = `B0`.`ID` WHERE 
`A0`.`USER_NAME` = ? AND `A0`.`USER_PASSWORD` = ?
```

I want to do this using annotation not by using XML.
My POJO classes are.

User.Java

```
@PersistenceCapable(table="User_Login")
public class User {
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="user_id")
private Integer userId=0;
@Persistent
@Column(name="user_profile_name")
private String userProfileName=null;  
@Persistent
@Column(name="user_email")
private String userEmail=null;
@Persistent
@Column(name="user_contact")
private String userContact=null;
@Persistent
@Column(name="user_name")
private String userName=null;
@Persistent
@Column(name="user_password")
private String userPassword=null;
@Persistent      
@Column(name="user_role_id")
private Integer userRoleId=0;       
@Persistent
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Role userRole;
```

Role.java

```
@PersistenceCapable(table="User_Role")
public class Role {
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user_role_id", fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
@Column(name="id")
private Integer roleId=0;
@Persistent
@Column(name="role")
private String role=null;
```

UserDaoImpl.java:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public List<User> getUser(String user_name, String user_password) {
    PersistenceManager pm = this.persistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManager();
    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    Query query = pm.newQuery(User.class);
    query.setFilter("this.userName == userNameParam && this.userPassword==userPasswordParam");
    query.declareParameters("String userNameParam, String userPasswordParam");
    query.setResult("this.userId,this.userRole.role");
  try {
    // Start the transaction
    tx.begin();
    List<User> result = (List<User>)query.execute(user_name,user_password);            
    if(result.size()>0){
        log.info(">>>>>00000000");
    }else{
        log.info("<<<<<<<=====000000");
    }
    // Commit the transaction, flushing the object to the datastore
    tx.commit();
    return result;
    }
    finally {
        if (tx.isActive())
        {
            // Error occurred so rollback the transaction
            tx.rollback();
        }
        pm.close();
    }
```

I am getting error:

```
 javax.jdo.JDOException: Exception thrown when executing query : SELECT 
 `A0`.`USER_ID`,`B0`.`ROLE` FROM `USER_LOGIN` `A0` LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 `USER_ROLE` `B0` ON `A0`.`USERROLE_ID_OID` = `B0`.`ID` WHERE 
 `A0`.`USER_NAME` = ? AND `A0`.`USER_PASSWORD` = ?
  NestedThrowables:
  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown   
  column 'A0.USERROLE_ID_OID' in 'on clause'
```

I have no idea from where USERROLE_ID_OID this is coming. I am very new in JDo. 
Please Help!!

Answer (score 0):

@ManyToOne and @OneToMany are JPA annotations, yet you use JDO annotations so remove them.

That column comes from the relation FK column "userRole". Specify the column name if you don't want that name. This is all documented in any decent JDO docs, such as those of DataNucleus

It does LEFT OUTER JOIN because it can be null; if you don't want to allow nulls in there then set the annotation/XML to do that